# Question about the rewards points system

Tags: reward-points

My question is, as magento default system, no rewards points are to be given to the orders below $100?

Comment: This is entirely up to configuration, which you would create (as far as EE goes - no idea about TPEs)

Answer (score 1):

In  default Magento Ce versions,*reward point extension does not exit*.

If you want to this feature then you need to use 3rd party extension

Comment: Or Enterprise Edition.

Comment: I am talking about the reward exchange rates in magento enterprise. And is it true that no rewards points are to be given to the orders below $100?